# Invoke an aws lambda function from another function with SQSEvent object

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a lambda function written in java with handle method signature as:

`public String handleRequest(SQSEvent sqsEvent, Context context){
     //Todo
}`

My lambda function accepts SQS event as request and process the logic.

In case, me lambda function fails somehow, I want to trigger it again by providing required input data manually. 
My approach is to create a new lambda function which will invoke my main lambda function. I will trigger my new lambda using APIGateway with required parameters.

**How can we create our own SQS event object to pass it as request body to my main lambda? What are the required parameters and structure of SQSEvent Object?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few things to consider:

1. Lambda retries failed invocations few times by default
2. If SQS is your event source, message will remain there until you delete it from queue in your code. If your function failed and didn't delete the message, it will be picked back up after visibility timeout expires
3. If the event consistently causes repeat failures, feeding it back to function will do no good and will induce endless loop

For cases like this it is recommended to have [DLQ](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-dead-letter-queues.html) setup, so you can isolate messages which fail consistently.

Now, it is possible that nature of your processing makes it safe to retry without fear of endless loop, in that case you can write a function which will pick up messages from DLQ and feed them back into main queue, no need to invoke "main" lambda directly. But that said, I would look really close at messages which end up in DLQ, they can be indicative of some processing bug in your code.

Comment: Thank you @Oleksii ! Like you said there might be bug in code. That is why, we want to manually trigger the lambda after fixing it. Is it good to create an alias/version of "main" lambda with a new handler which takes JSON object as input instead of SQSEvent object? I will pass only those fields which we need in our code basically. Also, can we limit the retries to lets say 3-4 times only before moving the failed event to DLQ?

Comment: @viruKundral SQS redrive policy allows you to specify how many times a message will appear in main queue before being redriven to DLQ. As for other questions, it's hard to say without knowing your setup

Comment: Instead of invoking our main lambda function from other lambda, we have just created a new handler method in our main lambda and executing it as an alias of it. But thanks for your idea on DLQ and retries. It really helped!

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to trigger with this:

```
    var body = "..."; // the expected format in the target lambda handler
    var evt = new SQSEvent();
    var msg = new SQSEvent.SQSMessage();
    msg.setBody(body);
    evt.setRecords(new ArrayList<>() {{ add(msg); }});

    var payload = new Gson().toJson(evt).replace("records", "Records");
    
    try {
        AWSLambdaAsyncClientBuilder.defaultClient()
            .invokeAsync((new InvokeRequest())
            .withInvocationType(InvocationType.RequestResponse)
            .withFunctionName(lambdaArn)
            .withPayload(payload))
            .get(5L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
    }
```